# How to change the me when receiving email on contact us

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I've created an contact us form using PHP Mailer, however the problem is when I received the email the name before you open it is me and I can't figured out how to fix it. Also I appreciate it if someone explain to me what is the different between Username and the add Address. Thank you in  advance.

Here is the me I'm referring to

[image]

```
<?php
use PHPMailer;

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = $_POST['body'];

require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/SMTP.php";
require_once "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

$mail = new PHPMailer();

//smtp settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "";
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->SetFrom("$email ", "$name");

//email settings
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['email']);
$mail->addAddress("");
$mail->Subject = ("$email ($subject)");
$mail->Body = $body;

if($mail->send()){
    $status = "success";
    $response = "Email is sent!";
}
else
{
    $status = "failed";
    $response = "Something is wrong: <br>" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

exit(json_encode(array("status" => $status, "response" => $response)));
}
```

Comment: use another email address that gmail will not identify as "me"

Comment: That's what happens when you send to yourself.

Comment: Thanks, If I used another email is the user's email will be replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending mail from the same email address to the same email address.

So, many email clients identify yourself as ***me***.

You will have to send using another email address, and you will be idenfied with your email/name.

**As [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2328185/jesse) said:** You can also send mail to another email, and it will usually not show ***me***.

Comment: or send to a different email address, probably the easier way to test

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Email address / use another Email address in script